# jQuery Mobile orientation image

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

Hello guys I have one question.

I have a strange problem with my jQuery mobile code on the devices.

Example iPad2:

1. So when I start the page in the phone in portrait mode the image looks like this (it should not be shrunk like this)
   http://oi43.tinypic.com/htd98i.jpg
2. When I turn it on landscape mode it still works ok 
   http://oi44.tinypic.com/2n1f8yw.jpg
3. When I change it on portrait mode again the horror happens
   http://oi43.tinypic.com/jfj3wh.jpg

After this it only changes between  mode 2 and 3.

I tried it on LG OptimusG  and it works simmillar, just on mode 1 it is not shrunked like on iPad.

I tried this in a separate page without JQM and it works fine when inserted in JQM  the problem starts.

I used ImageMapster script and I have this in my code (inside page content)

```
<img src="images/map.jpg" 
  usemap="#usa" style="width:100%;">

<map id="usa_image_map" name="usa">
    <area href="http://www.google.com" state="NH" full="New Hampshire" onclick="haha();" shape="poly" coords="251,99,376,138,477,180,601,279,644,319,593,369,512,332,535,291,527,282,524,281,499,329,387,281,382,289,316,269,323,254,280,235,285,220,254,206,249,219,234,212,192,74,248,74,236,98">
    <area href="http://www.google.com" state="NH" full="New Hampshire" onclick="haha2();" shape="poly" coords="109,205,136,302,191,287,184,262,212,254,210,246">
    <area href="http://www.google.com" state="NH" full="New Hampshire" onclick="haha3();" shape="poly" coords="67,45,98,158,199,200,155,68,104,68,101,47">

</map>
```

As I said the problem happens just when used with JQM and not with plain html.

if it helps: this is the code from ImageMapster http://jsfiddle.net/jamietre/jQG48/

I hope you understand the problem ...
I any other question just ask...

Hope you can help me solve the problem ... Thanks

**update:**

inside HTML:

```
<div role="content" class="ui-content">
    <img src="images/map.jpg" 
      usemap="#usa" style="width:100%;">

    <map id="usa_image_map" name="usa">
        <area href="http://www.google.com" state="NH" full="New Hampshire" onclick="haha();" shape="poly" coords="251,99,376,138,477,180,601,279,644,319,593,369,512,332,535,291,527,282,524,281,499,329,387,281,382,289,316,269,323,254,280,235,285,220,254,206,249,219,234,212,192,74,248,74,236,98">
        <area href="http://www.google.com" state="NH" full="New Hampshire" onclick="haha2();" shape="poly" coords="109,205,136,302,191,287,184,262,212,254,210,246">
        <area href="http://www.google.com" state="NH" full="New Hampshire" onclick="haha3();" shape="poly" coords="67,45,98,158,199,200,155,68,104,68,101,47">
    </map>    
</div>
```

The script is this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){
        var resizeTime = 100;     // total duration of the resize effect, 0 is instant
        var resizeDelay = 100;    // time to wait before checking the window size again
                                  // the shorter the time, the more reactive it will be.
                                  // short or 0 times could cause problems with old browsers.

        $('img').mapster({
            mapKey: 'state'
        });

        // Resize the map to fit within the boundaries provided

        function resize(maxWidth,maxHeight) {
             var image =  $('img'),
                imgWidth = image.width(),
                imgHeight = image.height(),
                newWidth=0,
                newHeight=0;

            if (imgWidth/maxWidth>imgHeight/maxHeight) {
                newWidth = maxWidth;
            } else {
                newHeight = maxHeight;
            }
            image.mapster('resize',newWidth,newHeight,resizeTime);   
        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            var curWidth = $(window).width(),
                curHeight = $(window).height(),
                checking=false;
            if (checking) {
                return;
                    }
            checking = true;
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                var newWidth = $(window).width(),
                   newHeight = $(window).height();
                if (newWidth === curWidth &&
                    newHeight === curHeight) {
                    resize(newWidth,newHeight); 
                }
                checking=false;
            },resizeDelay );
        }

    $(window).bind('resize',onWindowResize);


    });//]]>  

    function haha(){
        window.location.href = "glavna.html#pageprostori";
    };
    function haha2(){
        window.location.href = "glavna.html#pageopis";
    };
    function haha3(){
        window.location.href = "glavna.html#pagekontakt";
    };
</script>
```

I have this included in the html head

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://www.outsharked.com/scripts/jquery.imagemapster.js"></script>
```

Comment: are you wrapping markup in `content` div? `<div role="main" class="ui-content">` in case you're using jqm 1.4

Comment: yes I'am...  i tried to put it inside the content div and outside before the footer div .... no success...

Comment: have you tried reloading the map on `orientationchange` event?

Comment: i dont know if this is the problem because the even when started the image is "corrupted".... i will try but I doubt that orientationchange will solve this

Comment: when do you render map? call function?

Comment: with $(window).load(function(){

the html part is directly in the content div ...

Comment: pls update your question with that info and other details. when do you call it, how do you render it, etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46257/discussion-between-omar-and-litbe)